# How to merge 2 filed in mysql with 1 query

Tags: mysql

I have a table: `test(id, name1, name2)`
and data in table `test(1, "test1", "test2"`)
I using query:

```
Select name1 From test Where name1.name2 like '%t1te%'
```

> Can I using 2 field name1+name2 and result return is name1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're after [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
SELECT name1
FROM test
WHERE CONCAT(name1,name2) LIKE '%t1te%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can concatenate two columns and match the result to a pattern with `LIKE`:

```
SELECT name1
FROM   test
WHERE  CONCAT_WS('', name1, name2) LIKE '%t1te%';
```

The tricky part with the [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function or the concatenation operator `||` (with ANSI SQL mode) is this: if one of the string values is `NULL`, the result is `NULL`. You can avoid this with [`COALCESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), but this gets unwieldy quickly, because either one or both or none can be `NULL`.

There is a simpler way. Use [`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws), this function ignores `NULL` values; and use an empty string as separator as demonstrated above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONCAT` in such case

`WHERE CONCAT(name1,name2) like %searchName%`